# Did the B'omarr Order remain in their temple after Bib Fortuna, and Boba, took over

Tags: star-wars

I recently read that the new Extended Universe had the B'omarr monks (the brains carried by spider droids) retaking their temple after Jabba's death, but it reads as ambiguous as to what happened to them at the time of Fortuna's or Fett's reign. Has it been established whether the monks still roam the hallways and/or believe themselves to be in ownership of the building?

Comment: They make an appearance in this trailer for Book of Boba Fett; https://youtu.be/rOJ1cw6mohw

Comment: So it looks like they at least still exist on Tatooine, still not certain if they stayed in that building and/or took over parts of it.